# Custom fonts using xcode through attribute inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, uilabel

I am using Xcode 6.1 interface builder. 
I want to have a universal UILabel font throughout the app in which I can easily change. 
For example I want all my UILabel to use font 'A.otf' and later I would like to update all my UILabel to be something else like 'B.otf'

My first attempt is to subclass UILabel(lets call it MyCustomUILabel) and set its font attribute to whatever font I want. With this solution, I just have to make sure I set the UILabel to MyCustomUILabel in the identity inspector. And if I do need to change the font for all MyCustomUILabel, I will need to change it within the MyCustomUILabel class.

My second attempt is to use Xcode's built in custom font helper(attribute inspector -> font icon -> custom -> select my font). I was thinking if Xcode already provided a way to custom a font of my UILabel, then why create a custom class?

[image]

Using the Xcode built in custom way, I have a UILabel using 'GoodPro-Book.otf' as the custom font right now. I wanted to update this UILabel's font to 'Sanitarium.otf' and I was hoping that all I have to do is just rename my 'Sanitarium.otf' to 'GoodPro-Book.otf' and replace the one inside Xcode with this new one.

Of course it didn't work out.
So, I would like to ask, is this possible? in Xcode? Am I missing anything?

thanks, any suggestions and opinions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the font family and style are contained within the font file, so renaming the file doesn't have an effect. Unfortunately, I've never found a way to change Xcode's default font for a project (that would just make things too easy).

I think you're right in that the best way to change them all at once is to subclass UILabel and make sure you always use your subclass. Otherwise you have to change them all by hand.